# Resizing SWF document size in Flash, flips all the animations

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm building an animated ad with [Flash] CS6 for adwords, therefore I need the same ad in different dimensions.
I find out that clicking the wrench icon within Properties (image 1) I would be able to change the size of the document and also resize the animations by escalating them (image 2)

[image]

[image]

But after trying several attempts to resize my animation:
[image]

All i get is this:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function resizes all you objects keeping they aspect ration and using symbols 0.0 point as pivot. Sometimes it means that you have negative scale which mean mirror flips on one or two axises.
The better choice for you will be place all your content (animation and stuff) inside new MovieClip and resize it by tranform tool.

Comment: Thanks Aspiro! That worked like a charm! I created a MovieClip based on the background I had and then selected every frame in the animation, Copy frames, entered into the MC and Paste frames. Once I did that, I deleted the original animation frames and voilá! Thanks again!